# Interpretation of the cardinality of cokernel

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

I am wondering the interpretation of $|\operatorname{coker}\phi|$, where 
$$\phi:\mathbb{Z}[t]^n\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}[t]^n,(p_1(t),...,p_n(t))\mapsto(p_1(t),...,p_n(t))\cdot A,$$
and $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{Z}[t]$. Namely, $\phi$ is a linear map of $\mathbb{Z}[t]$-modules.

I know in the case of $\psi:\mathbb{Z}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^n,$ given that $\det \psi\neq 0$, we have $|\det\psi|=|\operatorname{coker}\psi|$. It has a clear geometric interpretation.

However, in the case of polynomial rings, we could have infinite $|\operatorname{coker}\phi|$ with non-vanished $\det A$. For example, $A=tI$.

My question: in this case, how should we interpret $|\operatorname{coker}\phi|$ and how could we relate it with $\det A$?

Comment: The cokernel (of a nonsurjective map) will always be a nontrivial $\Bbb{Q}$-vector space, hence countable. Thus nothing interesting can be said.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I changed the question to the situation I am really faced with.

Comment: What you can consider, and what might work out, is the length of a module. which is the supremum of lengths pf sequences of submodules and hence gives a more tangible idea of size than cardinality, which soon gets uncontrollable do to everything being countable or beyond.
https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00IU

Comment: @Enkidu Thank you. I think this is what I want. It's a good reference!